# How to pass the address of private data through main() function?

Tags: c++, oop

**printing elements of Linked list in reverse order**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace::std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
class linklist
{
    node* head;
public:
    linklist()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void create_list(int d);
    void reverse_print_list(node*);
```

}

```
void reverse_print_list(node* p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    reverse_print_list(p->next);
    cout << endl << p->data << " ";
}

int main()
{
    linklist l1;
    l1.create_list(10);
    l1.create_list(20);
    l1.create_list(30);
    l1.create_list(40);
    l1.create_list(50);
    l1.print_list(& head);  // Not allowed , gives compilation error 
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here I want to pass the address of **"head"**. But it is not accessible outside class as it is **private data**
How to solve this problem ???

Comment: Why do you want to pass it as a parameter? The list itself knows what the head is - it's its member.

Comment: @ molbdnilo : I am actually confused but I want to pass through main() function. And later I want to call print_list recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public overload which calls the recursive function with `head`:

```
void reverse_print_list() {reverse_print_list(head);}
```

The recursive function can now be made private.

Comment: Thank you friend. Your comment helped me. :)